# How to remove a package from the list of packages to be installed in apt-get?

Tags: apt

After I tried installing `vim` using `apt-get install`, `apt-get` keeps giving me a segmentation fault while trying to install `vim-runtime`. I'm pretty sure it's just with that one specific package, and whenever I try to do `apt-get install` to install any other package, `vim-runtime` is in the list of packages that will be installed, and it's always the first package that tries to install, so I can't install any other packages.

How can I remove `vim-runtime` from the list of packages that will be installed? It always shows up even if it is not a dependency of a package I want to install.

Note: This is on an Ubuntu rootfs running on ARM.

Comment: If `apt-get` segfaults — please [report it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Try `dpkg --remove vim-runtime` and see if it helps.

Comment: It gives me an error, saying: Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should reinstall it before attempting a removal. And of course, reinstalling also gives an error.

Comment: normally you would run `apt-get -f install` to fix install issues like this, but if it segfaults during configuration, I am not sure it will work...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and eventually I had to run `dpkg -S package-name` to find all the files associated with the package and delete them, which solved the problem.

Comment: mate just had a mare trying to find all the rubbish left over from brave. had to keep using this. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only correct way to make apt not try and install vim-runtime is to `sudo apt-get remove vim`.

Dpkg crashing while unpacking vim-runtime is either a serious bug, or an indication that something's wrong with your hardware.  (Although hardware errors are usually more random.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the .deb file for vim-runtime did not download properly, so `apt-get` crashes on it.

Look into `/var/cache/apt/archives` and delete this `vim-runtime*` file. To do so, run

```
gksudo -- nautilus --no-desktop /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

It's fine to erase any other .deb files from that folder, as these are cached .deb. files.

Comment: I don't have a vim-runtime file in that directory. I only have a lock file and an empty partial directory there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Back up and then remove these two files: `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` and `/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin`.
2. Then update the file cache

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Test `apt-get` now.

If it helps, please upload the broken cache files somewhere and post a link, I'd like to have a look at them.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. The package still shows up whenever I try to install or remove another package, or when I do apt-get autoremove.

Comment: I understand there is still the hanging package there, but does apt-get still give you segmentation fault?

Comment: Yep. I always get this error after it says Unpacking replacement vim-runtime...

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg received a segmentation fault.

I should have noted in the question that this is on an Ubuntu rootfs on ARM.