# How do I remove Brave completely?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-uninstall, purge, brave

Some time ago I installed Brave but I didn't like it, so I removed it with `sudo apt-get remove --purge brave-browser`. After some time I had to reinstall it because I needed a Chromium-based browser. As soon as I opened it it asked be to redeem my old BATs, so I deduce that apt-get left something in my system.

Now I don't need Brave anymore and I'm wondering how to remove it completely. I would use `sudo apt-get remove --purge brave-browser` once more but it looks like it doesn't really remove *everything* - what command should I use instead?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TIP**: Don't forget to **export your bookmarks & passwords**, just in case you want to import those in some other browser you want to use.

---

I had to do this all:

```
sudo apt remove brave-browser
sudo apt purge brave-browser
rm -rf ~/.config/BraveSoftware
rm -rf ~/.cache/BraveSoftware
```

[Reference](https://community.brave.com/t/how-to-safely-remove-uninstall-one-of-the-braves-out-of-linux/37091/2)

Answer (score 4):

for me Brave was taking up too much space. **One liner non-interactive answer**. Inspired by manoj L

`sudo apt -y remove brave-browser && sudo apt -y purge brave-browser && rm -rf ~/.config/BraveSoftware && rm -rf ~/.cache/BraveSoftware`

Answer (score 3):

A package stores personal and user specific configuration data in folder ~/.config

It is possible that sudo apt-get remove --purge brave-browser left those configuration files

Try:

```
cd ~/.config
ls -l | grep brave
```

If found:

```
rm -r ~/.config/FOLDER_NAME_HERE
```

Comment: It worked - the folder was `~/.config/BraveSoftware` -, but (from apt-get manual) _purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too)_, so shouldn't it remove automatically `~/.config/any-folder-related-to-the-removed-package`?

Comment: It deponds, not compulsory.

Comment: After all the above I also had to do this:
sudo apt remove brave-keyring

Comment: and to remove from ppa search  rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list

Comment: Thanks Jo_ ,This last one was essential to stop errors from occurring in relation to the missing key after removal. Christ. What a pain in the neck to get rid of Brave completely...

Answer (score 2):

This error was due to the repository still being in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

This is how you can remove everything:

```
apt purge brave-browser brave-keyring
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
sudo apt update
```

Take note of the `sudo` command as the `sources.list` folder is owned by the root