# Can't Update Brave Browser In Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ppa, 19.10, brave

I tried asking this [earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219959/ubuntu-19-10-updates-corrupted), but my problem still persists.

I'm running Brave Version 1.2.43 Chromium: 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my 19.10 Ubuntu laptop.

If I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following failures:

```
Get:13 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com eoan InRelease [3,162 B]                           
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ian-berke/ppa-drawers/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Err:13 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com eoan InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG A8580BDC82D3DC6C Brave Software <support@brave.com>
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ian-berke/ppa-drawers/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com eoan InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG A8580BDC82D3DC6C Brave Software <support@brave.com>
```

If I click on the [link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ian-berke/ppa-drawers/ubuntu/dists/), I don't see an `eoan` release, but I do see the `xenial` release on 2016-May-04. What file should I edit to tell Ubuntu to use that release?

One of the [references](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) to my previous attempt suggested that I install ppa-purge.  I did, but no joy.

I'm lost on how to solve my specific problem.  I'd like to update Brave.  I'm sorry to not know better, but I'd appreciate advice on a specific corrective action to take.

i tried [removing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217043/how-do-i-remove-brave-completely) Brave completely:

```
sudo apt remove brave-browser
sudo apt purge brave-browser
rm -rf ~/.config/BraveSoftware
rm -rf ~/.cache/BraveSoftware
```

I thought this would solve the problem.  But I still get that same error when I execute `sudo apt-get update`.

I see that Ubuntu 19.10 reaches the end of its life next month.  Is the answer to upgrade to 20.10 and try again?

Comment: By opening the link in your error (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ian-berke/ppa-drawers/ubuntu/dists/) you can quickly see the release it supports.. or better yet before adding view the details https://launchpad.net/~ian-berke/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-drawers where it's pretty easy to spot 2016 was the last update; why add it when it won't have any support for any release after that (ie. 19.10).  You also mention 20.10?  that comes out in October (why it's 20.10; 2020-October using the *yy.mm* format of Ubuntu releases), 19.10 upgrades to 20.04 LTS not to 20.10

Comment: I get 404 from that link.

Comment: What I really want is updates to Brave.  Possible to uninstall and reinstall?  http://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2019/10/how-to-install-brave-browser-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: I've updated my question with more details.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the obsolote repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers
```

Fetch newest Brave Browser's key.

```
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
```

Update the index repository, try installing brave once again.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave-browser
```

Comment: I would award you 1,000 points if I could.  This was the fix.  Thank you so much for your generous help.

Comment: @duffymo You can give more points by issuing a bounty and then awarding the above answer.