# Opera repo not signed due to GPG error NO_PUBKEY

Tags: apt, 22.04, gnupg, opera, signature

I am unable to perform software updates on my new Ubuntu 22.04 installation due to the following error/issue:

```
Warning: GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY XX3C36XXXDE1B7XX

Error: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

I have attempted various solutions from checking online but nothing seems to solve this issue.

**UPDATE**

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/618353) provided in the suggested duplicate [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13065/618353). The first method didn't work and then I tried the ALTERNATE METHOD and here are the results from that:

```
> sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key XX3C36XXXDE1B7XX

gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key XX3C36XXXDE1B7XX: public key "Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2021 <packager@opera.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

> sudo gpg -a --export XX3C36XXXDE1B7XX | sudo apt-key add -

Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK

> sudo apt-get update
                                                            
Get:10 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,590 B]                                                           
Err:10 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY XX3C36XXXDE1B7XX
W: GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DD3C368A8DE1B7A0
E: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Unfortunately I am still receiving the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I have just updated my question and added result from suggested solution and this is still an issue. Looked at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: Just in case someone else has the same issue as me and the above suggested answers does not work, like it didn't for me, I ended up removing all sources relating to Opera. I found this answer over at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179621/how-to-remove-the-packages-causing-gpg-error-at-once